# Answering your own Question

Tags: discussion

What is the etiquette of answering your own question.

If you already know the optimum solution to a question,
how long do you give others before posting the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably about (or at least triggered by) [your freeing a binary tree question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/478/free-a-binary-tree)?

To the extent that the point of this business is having fun, I'd say you should wait until

- a couple of days have passed so that people have time to explore the problem

or

- someone else posts an equivalent solution

Comment: I can't say it was not motivated by my own question. But it was general meant as a question for all.